# How do I disarm enemies in Assassins Creed Revelations?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm stuck in one of the master assassin missions - I'm only allowed to disarm enemies but I can't find a proper move in the game tutorials nor do I find anything in the handbook.

Anyone knows the necessary key on the keyboard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To perform a disarm, you need to be unarmed and do the "counter kill."  To be unarmed, that means no sword, no hidden blade, but pure fists (that's <kbd>4</kbd> on the keyboard by default).  The counter kill is **High Profile** + **Weapon Arm** when an enemy attacks you and that should disarm them and you steal their weapon.  That should be <kbd>Right Mouse</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> by default.  Pressing <kbd>4</kbd> again when holding a picked up weapon will drop it.

Comment: Of course, I'm assuming you are actually using the Mouse + Keyboard combination and not just Keyboard only.

Comment: Sure, it's Mouse and Keyboard! I gonna try this as soon as I'm back home! Thank you :)!

Comment: This isn't working...

Comment: @SaMu3L There isn't much more to it than that. The tutorial would basically consist of Jeff Mercado's answer. You can practice the moves in-game, though I don't recall the menu options needed to get there off the top of my head.

Comment: @SaMu3L It is imperative that you are unarmed first.  It won't work unless you are.  Then you have to perform the "counter-kill" action when an enemy is attacking you.  That means holding high-profile and pressing attack the moment the enemy goes in and swings at you.